# Improve the performce of a MongoDB query which uses a "$where" expression

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, mongodb-query

I need to run the following query on a MongoDB server:

```
QUERY = {
    "$and" : [
        {"x" : {'$gt' : 1.0}},
        {"y" : {'$gt' : 0.1}},
        {"$where" : 'this.s1.length < this.s2.length+3'}
    ]
}
```

This query is very slow, due to the JavaScript expression which the server needs to execute on every document in the collection.

Is there any way for me to optimize it?

I thought about using the `$size` operator, but I'm not really sure that it works on strings, and I'm even less sure on how to compare its output on a pair of strings (as is the case here).

Here is the rest of my script, in case needed:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

USERNAME        = ...
PASSWORD        = ...
SERVER_NAME     = ...
DATABASE_NAME   = ...
COLLECTION_NAME = ...

uri = 'mongodb://{}:{}@{}/{}'.format(USERNAME,PASSWORD,SERVER_NAME,DATABASE_NAME)
mongoClient = MongoClient(uri)
collection = mongoClient[DATABASE_NAME][COLLECTION_NAME]
cursor = collection.find(QUERY)
print cursor.count()
```

The `pymongo` version is 3.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation framework, which provides [$strLenCP](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strLenCP/#exp._S_strLenCP) to get length of a string and [$cmp](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cmp/#exp._S_cmp) to compare them:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $match: {
        "x" : {'$gt' : 1.0},
        "y" : {'$gt' : 0.1}
      }
    },
    {
      $addFields: {
        str_cmp: { $cmp: [ { $strLenCP: "$s1" }, { $add: [ { $strLenCP: "$s2" }, 3 ] } ] }
      }
    },
    {
      $match: {
        "str_cmp": -1,
      }
    }
  ]
)
```

Comment: Will this insert new data into the DB?

Comment: why? do you need to fetch or insert?

Comment: BTW, as you can see in my query, I am trying to aggregate those cases in which the length of `s1` is smaller than the length of `s2` + 3. How can I adjust your solution to do this?

Comment: I don't need to insert, I just want to make sure that your solution doesn't, since I'm not sure what the `$addFields` operator does, and by the name it sounds like insertion.

Comment: Ah, missed the +3 thingy. See my update. It adds the `str_cmp` field to the result, but it does not modify the data at rest. You can either ignore the extra field, or add another projection stage to remove it.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, you're missing about a dozen quotes up there (keep in mind I'm using Python, not Mongo Shell).

Comment: It's javascript syntax used in mongodb shell. I am not quite familiar with pymongo unfortunately, but if it needs extra quotes, please add them as required.

Comment: Yes, I am also unable to call `cursor.count()`, since the returned object is something called `CommandCursor`. Anyway, I'll make sure that it contains the data that I expect it to...